# Allowed range of parameters in an inequality

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

I have an inequality as following:

```
m2/r + m1/r^0.5 < 0
```

I need to understand the allowed range of m1 and m2 that satisfies the above inequality for different values of r. I tried this:

```
In[96]:= Manipulate[RegionPlot[m2/r + m1/r^0.5 < 0, {m1, -1, 1}, {m2, -1, 1}, 
FrameLabel -> {m1, m2}], {r, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

This Plot gives me the information I need but the problem is this plot is not good for being in a paper. Because in the paper it is not possible to change the value of r and see what happens as r changes. Is there any other way to get the information I need and visualize it in a way that is suitable to put in a paper?

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
Reduce[m2/r + m1/r^(1/2) < 0 && r > 0 && r <= 20, {m1, m2}, Reals]
```

> `0 < r <=  20 && ((m1 <= 0 && m2 < Sqrt[m1^2 r]) || (m1 > 0 &&  m2 < -Sqrt[m1^2 r]))`

answers that question.

Addition.

```
RegionPlot3D[ 0 < r <= 20 && ((m1 <= 0 && m2 < Sqrt[m1^2 r]) || (m1 > 0 && 
  m2 < -Sqrt[m1^2 r])), {r, 0, 20}, {m1, -5, 5}, {m2, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, Thank you very much. Is it possible to visualize it?